# Dynamic React path Routing not matching url but matches on reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

.I am trying to move to a url using dynamic routing and using the React Link tag. The problem is that it changes the url but does not re-render the ui. When I use an anchor tag or when the page is refreshed it renders. I have been trying to detect the problem but I am currently stuck. I implemented somethings similar furhter below and its working fine.

Here is a snippet of my App.js

```
// Front end pages
if (isFrontEndPage()) {
    return (
        <Layout className="app-container">
            <AppHeader />
            <Layout>
                <AppSidebar />
                <Content className="app-content" breakpoint="lg">
                  <div className="container" style={{ minHeight: '100vh', padding: '10px' }} >
                        <Switch>   
                            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                            <Route path="/pricing" exact component={Pricing} />
                            <Route path="/features" exact component={Features} />

                            <Route path="/help/search/result.html" exact component={Post} />
                            <Route path="/help" exact render={(props) => <Redirect to="/p/help/invoices/index.html" /> } />
                            // I have a problem with this
                            <Route path="/p/:postType/:postCategoryUrlTitle/:postUrlTitle.html" component={Post} />
                            // I also have a problem with this
                            <Route path="/:postUrlTitle" component={Post} />
                            
                            <Route component={NotFound} />
                        </Switch>
                      </div>
                    </Content>
                </Layout>
                <AppFooter />
            </Layout>
        )

    }

    return (
        <Layout className="app-container">
            <AppHeader />
            <Layout>
                <AppSidebar />
                <Content className="app-content" breakpoint="lg">
                  <div className="container" style={{ minHeight: '100vh', padding: '10px' }} >
                    <Switch>   
                        // The below similar links actually render accurately with dynamic routing
                        <PrivateRoute path="/posts/info-posts/new" component={InfoPost} />
                        <PrivateRoute path="/posts/info-posts/info-post/:infoPostId" component={InfoPost} />
                        <PrivateRoute path="/posts/info-posts" component={InfoPosts} />
                         
                        <**************** OTHER PATHS ***********************>
                        <PrivateRoute component={NotFound} />
                    </Switch>
                  </div>
                </Content>
            </Layout>
            <AppFooter />
        </Layout>
    );

}

export default App;
```

Below is a snippet of my Index.js

```
  ............
  ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <AuthProvider>
            <App />
        </AuthProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. You should reduce your code to a minimal example (i.e. the least code that illustrates the problem). That makes it much more likely that somebody will read it (i.e. is willing to spend the time to understand your code).

Comment: Thanks for the comment @kca. I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

When using React's Link component, the page doesn't refresh, it only switches the component/view, that is the way Link works. If you use anchor tag the page refreshes. Not sure what exactly is going on in your app, but from what I can see, I noticed that you are linking same component for more routes, maybe that is why your UI doesn't change

Comment: It actually works with an anchor tag. You answer actually made me to notice that the view changes when linking from a different component to the Post component and it also changes when linking from Post component to another component. I was wondering where the problem was and how I can change the view based on the url if I am already in the Post component and the other url's still link to the same Post component since its a dynamic route. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem. Since I was already in the component that I wanted to route to, all I needed to do was to use React hook 'useRouteMatch' to actually render the component again using 'useEffect' when a change in params property of 'useRouteMatch' is detected.

```
...
const {postType, postCategoryUrlTitle, postUrlTitle } = useRouteMatch().params;
...

useEffect(() => {
    // Now do stuff with the params
}, [postType, postCategoryUrlTitle, postUrlTitle]);
```